# unusable index turns valid

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, informatica

I'm trying to change index on a few tables to unusable for better performance on the insert, using a procedure(in informatica).
The procedure works fine and the index turn unusable.
The problem is when i run the map after(that does normal insert) the index returns to be valid. 
What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the 'map' that you run? Are you sure that this procedure doesn't rebuild unusable indexes? What is dba_objects.last_ddl_time for this index? Maybe it would be easier to just drop the index? But, again, this 'map' could re-create them. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/indexes004.htm#CIHJCEAJ

Comment: The map is something in informatica. Anyways I figured it out.. in the map it truncate the target table which change the unusable to valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a table is truncated the associated index segments are also truncated. As there is no data the index is not unusable any more.